# Toggle Read more/Read less using show_char & content.length

Tags: jquery

How can I toggle 'Read more'/'Read less' using the following code?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var show_char = 280;
  var ellipses = "... ";
  var content = $(".aaa").html();

  if (content.length > show_char) {
    var a = content.substr(0, show_char);
    var b = content.substr(show_char - content.length);
    var html = a + "<span class='truncated'>" + ellipses + "<a class='read-more'>Read more</a></span><span class='truncated' style='display:none'>" + b + "</span>";
    $(".aaa").html(html);
  }

  $(".read-more").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".aaa .truncated").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aaa">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the `text` of `read-more` element is `Read more` or not depending on this change text of `a` tag . Also , move whole `a` tag outside `span` tag else it will hide when you toggle your `span` tags.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var show_char = 280;
  var ellipses = "... ";
  var content = $(".aaa").text(); //change here ..

  if (content.length > show_char) {
    var a = content.substr(0, show_char);
    var b = content.substr(show_char - content.length);
    var html = a + "<span class='truncated'>" + ellipses + "</span><span class='truncated' style='display:none'>" + b + "</span><a class='read-more' href='#'>Read more</a>"; //move read more outside
    $(".aaa").html("<p>" + html + "</p>");
  }

  $(".read-more").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".read-more").text() == "Read more" ? $(".read-more").text("Read less") : $(".read-more").text("Read more") //change here..
    $(".aaa .truncated ").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aaa">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using `$(".aaa").html()` so this will take `p` tag as well .Instead you can use `$(".aaa").text()` and then you can manipulate your htmls according to your needs.

Comment: This is great the only thing is that , If I write i.e.   <p>Lorem Ipsum <a href="https://google.com">
Google</a> is simply dummy text , the link doesn't appear now .. why?

Comment: You need to make `a` tag blue color ? If yes , use `href='#'` inside `a` tag.

Comment: I did it but hyperlink do not highlight.. Can you change it in your answer? Use inside Lorem Ipsum whatever link you want.. thanks a lot @Swati

Comment: Updated again .

Comment: You made 'read more', 'read less' blue. This is perfect. But what I want is to put a link in <p> Lorem Ipsum. If I do for example the word dummy hyperlink, it does not turn blue in Lorem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233182/discussion-between-swati-and-ricky).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this feature multiple times in a page, here is the solution (Improved Swati's solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67790521/1262673)

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  var show_char = 280;
  var ellipses = "... ";
  $(".long-text").each(function (index) {
    var $longText = $(this);
    var content = $longText.text();
    if (content.length > show_char) {
      var firstPart = content.substr(0, show_char);
      var secondPart = content.substr(show_char - content.length);
      var html = firstPart + "<span class='truncated'>" + ellipses + "</span><span class='truncated' style='display:none'>" + secondPart + "</span><a class='btn btn-xs btn-secondary read-more' href='#'>▼ Read more</a>";
      $longText.html("<p>" + html + "</p>");
    }
  })
  
  $(".read-more").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html() == '▼ Read more' ? $this.html('▲ Read less') : $this.html('▼ Read more') //change here..
    $this.parent("p").find(".long-text").toggle();
    $this.parent("p").find(".truncated").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="long-text">adaptive algorithmic trading system Main purpose of this project was transferring data of algorithmic output which produced adaptive algorithmic trading system Main purpose of this project was transferring data of algorithmic output which produced adaptive algorithmic trading system Main purpose of this project was transferring data of algorithmic output which produced adaptive algorithmic trading system Main purpose of this project was transferring data of algorithmic output which produced adaptive algorithmic trading system Main purpose of this project was transferring data of algorithmic output which produced adaptive algorithmic trading system Main purpose of this project was transferring data of algorithmic output which produced adaptive algorithmic trading system Main purpose of this project was transferring data of algorithmic output which produced </p>

<p class="long-text">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  </p>
```